# Scrapy Example: example.com/page.aspx?id=1

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm having trouble finding a scrapy example where I want to crawl a site with an example URL like:

```
example.com/page.aspx?id=1
```

There will be one item on `page.aspx` depending on the `id`. I want to pass in the minimum number  (e.g. `15`) then have scrapy run until it gets the top id (e.g. `25`).

Once the crawler reaches the top id then there will be a message that says something about 'inconvenience' rather than `404` or some other code.

Mostly I am wondering how to iterate an address with a number. I'm not interested in scrapy discovering and following links on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    minimum = 15
    maximum = 25

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(self.minimum, self.maximum + 1):
            url = 'http://example.com/page.aspx?id={}'.format(i)
            yield scrapy.Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```